# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cosmos DB connection configuration 'CosmosDB' does not exist

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-trigger

I have a blob trigger function. this code snippet from **init**.py:

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
endpoint = os.environ["connect__accountEndpoint"]
client = CosmosClient(
    url = endpoint,
    credential = credential
)
database_name = os.environ["cosmosDatabase"]
container_name = os.environ["cosmosColl"]
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
```

This is my local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "cosmosDatabase": "",
    "cosmosColl": "",
    "connect__accountEndpoint": "",
    "connect__clientId": "",
    "BlobConnStr": ""
  }
}
```

This is my function.json :

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "contracts/{name}",
      "connection": "BlobConnStr"
    },
    {
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "%cosmosDatabase%",
      "collectionName": "%cosmosColl%",
      "connect__accountEndpoint": "connect__accountEndpoint",
      "createIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.contracts_blob_trigger. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cosmos DB connection configuration 'CosmosDB' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

I have a problem in Configuration part between json files. How can I handle this error?

Comment: replace `connect__accountEndpoint` with `connectionStringSetting` in function.json file

Comment: This is my host.json:                               {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Preview",
    "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "blobs": {
        "maxDegreeOfParallelism": 4
    },
    "cosmosDB": {
      "connectionMode": "Gateway"
  }
  }
}

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin, I am still getting same error

Comment: This is my [host](https://i.imgur.com/ZgD7a1F.png) and [function.json](https://i.imgur.com/l5PMsFy.png) file

Answer (score 0):

First issue is `connect__accountEndpoint`. You are using a special notation in Azure Functions that normally means that there is nested JSON:

```
{
  "connect": 
  {
     "accountEndpoint":"...."
  }
}
```

In the `Values` section. But your `Values` section does not have a `connection` node with the `accountEndpoint` and `clientId` attributes.

But looking at what you are using, you seem to be attempting to use MSI Authentication (accountEndpoint + clientId) which is incompatible with the version of the Extension you seem to be using.

MSI Auth is supported in Extension and Bundles 4.x, for which the names of the attributes and configurations are different (`collectionName` no longer exists, its `containerName`).

Please make sure you are using the latest bundle (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/migrate-cosmos-db-version-3-version-4?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-python), and then your `function.json` would look like:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "contracts/{name}",
      "connection": "BlobConnStr"
    },
    {
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "%cosmosDatabase%",
      "containerName": "%cosmosColl%",
      "connection": "connect",
      "createIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And your `host.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "cosmosDatabase": "",
    "cosmosColl": "",
    "connect": {
         "accountEndpoint":"",
         "clientId":""
    },
    "BlobConnStr": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: from this result i got this error: Azure.Storage.Blobs: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:538f1ee3-701e-006a-2362-4f4bd2000000
Time:2024-01-25T07:46:42.5784466Z
[2024-01-25T07:46:42.606Z] Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
[2024-01-25T07:46:42.607Z] ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Comment: **This error is not related to Cosmos DB**, but Azure Storage. Could be that the connection string you are using for Blob is incorrect/does not have enough permissions

Comment: I am using correct connection string for blob. i change my config like that:    function.json: {
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "contracts/{name}",
      "connection": "BlobConnStr_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "doc",
      "databaseName": "%cosmosDatabase%",
      "containerName": "%contractsContainer%",
      "connection": "Connect",
      "createIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}

Comment: local.settings.json:{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "cosmosDatabase": "",
    "contractsContainer": "",
    "Connect__clientId": "",
    "BlobConnStr_STORAGE": "",
    "Connect__accountEndpoint": "",
    "Connect__credential":  "managedidentity"
  }
}

Comment: I am getting this error: Result: Failure
Exception: CredentialUnavailableError: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint

Comment: from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential,ManagedIdentityCredential

# # user-assigned managed identity
managed_identity_client_id =  os.environ['Connect__clientId']
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=managed_identity_client_id)
endpoint = os.environ["Connect__accountEndpoint"]
print("endpoint: ",endpoint)
# credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
print("credential: ",credential)
client = CosmosClient(
    credential=credential,
    url = endpoint
)